# sql server vs postgres in .net SqlConnection vs NpgsqlConnection

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, postgresql, ado.net

I'm experimenting with postgres and sql server

the same query in sql server gives me:

```
CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 800 ms.
```

and in postgres:

```
38 ms
```

but when I do the same query via .net using SqlConnection,SqlCommand and NpgsqlConnection,NpgsqlCommand

the sqlserver is 30% faster

can anyone explain this ?

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to explain? The same query runs in a slightly different amount of time on two completely different database platforms; that doesn't seem surprising. Put it another way, do you expect the query to run in exactly the same time, despite the completely different software stacks? If so, why?

Comment: @Pondlife sql server is slower (800 ms) when executing the query directly in management studio vs postgres in psql console, but via .net postgres is slower by 30%

Comment: Sounds like you should talk with the developer of Npgsql and see why your psql query is faster than your .Net invoked query.  Most likely there is some overhead with the Npgsql or maybe it's doing some funny business to your query. Be nice to see your query and your .net code.

Comment: @StarShip3000 my query is `select * from foo`

Answer (score 1):

A quick guess is Npgsql is not as optimized as the Microsoft SQL Server .net connection library.  You pretty much proved that when the SQL Server query was 30% faster when invoked via .net.  Did you run the test a few times one after another for both databases? Just make sure SQL Server wasn't caching data making it look blazing fast compared to PostgreSQL going out to disk for the same data.

Comment: yes I know about this, 2nd time they are both faster (postgres caches also, I guess), but sql server is still 30% faster, doesn't matter 1st time or 2nd, although there is a big difference between 1st and 2nd time you execute the same query

Comment: @Omu Plus you have to keep in mind all the variables at work here. Are both databases on the same hardware?  With the same load? Are both configured to be exactly the same?  Lot's of possible variables at work here.  But it appears that you are showing it probably has to do with the .net drivers. With the SQL Server being more per formant at least under your select * from foo test, which is a really unrealistic query to be running for real world test results.  Normally never select *, and it's rare you would select all rows from a table unless you are caching a look up tables values.

Comment: servers are exactly the same, anyway that doesn't really matters, because posrgre is much faster than sql server but not via NpgSql,.net

Comment: @Omu have you tried the Devart driver for Postgres?  I wouldn't be surprised if it was faster than Npgsql.

Comment: @Cory Grimster as a matter of fact I did tried it, and it almost 2 times slower, but it does support TransactionScope(), so it is very possible that this is what I'm going to use